# Deserializing shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat only for once for facial landmark detection in real time in android studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opencv, dlib

I am trying to detect facial landmark using opencv ,dlib library in android studio.
I can capture image and detect landmarks from the image.
But I am facing problem when I am trying to detect facial landmark in real time.

Because I am deserializing shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat file for each frame.

`onCameraFrame method of MainActivity.Java`

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
{
    matInput =inputFrame.rgba();

        NativeClass.LandmarkDetection(matInput.getNativeObjAddr(), matOutput.getNativeObjAddr());

    return matOutput;
}
```

`NativeClass.Java`

```
package com.example.user.drowsinessdetection;


public class NativeClass {
    public native static String getMessage();
    public native static void LandmarkDetection(long addrInput,long addrOutput);
}
```

The cpp file for Landmark detection:

`com_example_user_drowsinessdetection_NativeClass.cpp`

```
#include <com_example_user_drowsinessdetection_NativeClass.h>
#include <dlib/geometry/rectangle.h>


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
Java_com_example_user_drowsinessdetection_NativeClass_getMessage
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass){
env->NewStringUTF("JNI message");
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_user_drowsinessdetection_NativeClass_LandmarkDetection
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass thiz, jlong addrInput, jlong addrOutput){
    Mat& image = *(Mat*)addrInput;
    Mat& dst = *(Mat*)addrOutput;

    faceDetectionDlib(image, dst);
}



void faceDetectionDlib(Mat& img, Mat& dst){

    try {
        frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
        shape_predictor pose_model;
       deserialize("storage/emulated/0/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")>>pose_model;
        cv_image<bgr_pixel>cimg(img);

        std::vector<dlib::rectangle> faces = detector(cimg);
        std::vector<full_object_detection> shapes;
        int k=faces.size();

        for(unsigned long i = 0;i < k; ++i)
            shapes.push_back(pose_model(cimg,faces[i]));

        dst = img.clone();
        renderToMat(shapes, dst);
       }
    catch (serialization_error& e)
    {
        cout<<endl<<e.what()<<endl;
    }

}

void renderToMat(std::vector<full_object_detection>& dets, Mat& dst){
Scalar color;
int sz = 3,l;
color = Scalar(0,255,0);
//chin line
l=dets.size();
for(unsigned long idx = 0; idx < l; idx++) {

    //left eye
    for (unsigned long i = 37; i <= 41; ++i)
        cv::line(dst, Point(dets[idx].part(i).x(), dets[idx].part(i).y()),
                 Point(dets[idx].part(i - 1).x(), dets[idx].part(i - 1).y()), color, sz);
    cv::line(dst, Point(dets[idx].part(36).x(), dets[idx].part(36).y()),
             Point(dets[idx].part(41).x(), dets[idx].part(41).y()), color, sz);
    //right eye
    for (unsigned long i = 43; i <= 47; ++i)
        cv::line(dst, Point(dets[idx].part(i).x(), dets[idx].part(i).y()),
                 Point(dets[idx].part(i - 1).x(), dets[idx].part(i - 1).y()), color, sz);
    cv::line(dst, Point(dets[idx].part(42).x(), dets[idx].part(42).y()),
             Point(dets[idx].part(47).x(), dets[idx].part(47).y()), color, sz);
    //lips out part

}
}
```

I don't want execute this line

`frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();`
and

`deserialize("storage/emulated/0/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")>>pose_model;`

for each and every frame.

So How can I do these only once and then use these for all other frames?

I am a newbie.
Please help.

Sorry for my poor English. :)